# Meaning of き in 唾をぶっかけて.き.やがるからな。

Tags: grammar, meaning, syntax

If I am correct, then ぶっかける and やがる are verbs but what is the き doing in between them?

Full sentence:
~
この辺では、言葉に気をつけた方がいいぜ。町のこちら側に住んでいるやつらは、口笛を吹いただけでも顔に唾をぶっかけてきやがるからな。
~
You have to be careful about what you say around here. People on this side of town will spit in your face just for whistling.

Comment: Always nice to see bukkake in context

Comment: Note that even without this き there, it would still consist of three parts as ぶっかけて・（い）・やがる. Without the second, いる, it would be ぶっかけ・やがる.

Answer (score 3):

There are three components:

- ぶっかける
- くる
- やがる

The difference between ぶっかけやがる and ぶっかけてきやがる is that the latter has くる（来る） → き in it. If you remove やがる and make it more polite, the expression would be ぶっかけてくる.

By having くる in it you make it clearer that you are the presumed recipient of the action. In this case, the interpretation that there are third-party recipients are unlikely so it doesn't add much, though.

Notice that whose 顔 is unspecified in Japanese, unlike "your face" in your translation. I think くる provides the same information in a different way.